# How can I remove child elements in the piece of xml below?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get this xml transform

```
<root> <c.head ampexmnem="dl1"><h.info><text>CALENDAR YEAR: 2012</text></h .info></c .head> </root>

<root> <dl1>CALENDAR YEAR: 2012</dl1> </root>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Your XML is invalid ("escaped" quotes and closing tags with space in the tag name).

Comment: It was inside of a java program

Comment: There's still an error in the closing tags. I tried to edit it directly, but it wouldn't let me remove less than six characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c.head">
    <xsl:element name="{@ampexmnem}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, the actual pattern depends on the actual structure of your documents. I suspect there's more than one branch in them.

Comment: There can be more than one child elements inside of root, I just wanted to remove c.head ampexmnem="dl1"><h.info><text> and replace that with <dl1>

Comment: Are there different `ampexmnem` attributes? Should the resulting element have different names according to this attribute's value?

Comment: yes, there is an attribute value of dl1 and another of til, and I wanted to get only dl1 transformed and not til

Comment: that fine. Thanks. I only selected the element with that attribute